# Replace words including numbers in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`t = "Text with numbers such as 58, 22nd, 53m2, number9 and foo44bar"`

I would like to put `<span>`'s around the numbers like this:

```
t.gsub(/(\d+)([[:alnum:]]+)/,"<span>\\1\\2</span>") =>
"Text with numbers such as <span>58</span>, <span>22nd</span>, <span>53m2</span>, number9 and foo<span>44bar</span>"
```

The only problem I am still having is when the word does not start with a number like `number9 and "foo<span>44bar</span>`, I also tried

`t.gsub(/([[:alnum:]]+)(\d+)([[:alnum:]]+)/,"<span>\\1\\2\\3</span>")`,

but this is also not quite correct.

I am sure I am just not seeing some detail, some help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t.gsub(/([[:alnum:]]*(\d+)[[:alnum:]]*)/, "<span>\\1</span>")
```